# Display the image from mysql database in php laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, localhost

I'm trying to display image from mysql database. it's just showing the name of the image. Image is not displaying. how to make it display? 
I'm using laravel framework with localhost. Kindly look into it and help me out..

my controller page code...

```
public function stores(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            //'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|max:2048',
            'description' => 'required'
        ]);



        if($request->hasFile('image')){
          $image = $request->file('image');
          $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
          Image::make($image)->resize(300, 300)->save( storage_path('/uploads/' . $filename ) );
          $blog->image = $filename;
        }

        $blog = new Blogform;
        $blog->first_name = $request->firstname;
        $blog->last_name = $request->lastname;
        $blog->email = $request->email;
        $blog->image = $request->image;
        $blog->description = $request->description;
        $blog->save();
        return redirect('/blog')->with('successMsg', 'Blog form Submitted Successfully');
    }



`my view page code..`

@foreach($blogs as $blog)
<tr>
    <th scope="row"> {{ $blog->id}} </th> 
    <td> {{ $blog->first_name}} </td> 
    <td> {{ $blog->last_name}} </td> 
    <td> {{ $blog->email}} </td> 
    <td> {{ $blog->image}} </td> 
    <td> {{ $blog->description}} </td> 
    <td> {{ $blog->created_at}} </td> 
    <td> {{ $blog->updated_at}} </td> 
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: whr is your image tag with url?

Comment: If you mean storing photos in a database, You need to save the image as a base64 in database.The image is stored in the database without saving to the server.The image path is stored in the code above.

Comment: @user11010754 could you please check my answer and give us a feed back

Answer (score 2):

Modify you'r controller

```php
$blog = new Blogform;
$blog->first_name = $request->firstname;
$blog->last_name = $request->lastname;
$blog->email = $request->email;

if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Image::make($image)->resize(300, 300)->save(storage_path('/uploads/' . $filename));
    $blog->image = $filename;
     } else {
          $blog->image = '';
     }
     $blog->description = $request->description;
     $blog->save();
     return redirect('/blog')->with('successMsg', 'Blog form Submitted Successfully');
     }
```

use `Storage::url()` function with `img`  tag

```php
@foreach($blogs as $blog)
<tr>
    <th scope="row"> {{ $blog->id}} </th> 
    <td> {{ $blog->first_name}} </td> 
    <td> {{ $blog->last_name}} </td> 
    <td> {{ $blog->email}} </td> 
    <td> 
        <img src="{{  Storage::disk('public')->url('uploads/'.$blog->image) }}" alt="image" width="50">
    </td> 
    <td> {{ $blog->description}} </td> 
    <td> {{ $blog->created_at}} </td> 
    <td> {{ $blog->updated_at}} </td> 
</tr>
@endforeach
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#file-urls

**Note : -** make sure in `.env` `APP_URL` is correct

Comment: wouldnt this still print the url rather than showing the image as `img` tag is not thr?

Comment: @Cerlin ok i added image tag as well

Comment: @KamleshPaul please check his code.Hes saving original file name into the table.

Comment: @NipunTharuksha he is only storing image name not `storage_path()`

Comment: @KamleshPaul yes he is renaming image but saving original name to db. So he cant find a image with that name in his uploads folder

Comment: @NipunTharuksha `storage_path()` then inside `/upload` folder please check once code  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-storage-path

Comment: @KamleshPaul  I know what you are trying to point out. Im trying to say that hes searching for a image with its original name. So what ever the method you use he wont be able to find that image in his uploads folder

Comment: `$blog->image = $request->image` hes saving original file name into db but image almost uploaded to upload folder after renaming it   ` Image::make($image)->resize(300, 300)->save( storage_path('/uploads/' . $filename ) ); `

Comment: @KamleshPaul I can see that you have CHANGED YOUR ANSWER AS i MENTIONED IN MINE.

Comment: Actually the image is not uploading to the database
since in ` $blog->image = ' '; ` it's null, so empty is assigning to the database.

Comment: then my be your file is not sending by post method have you added encryption typ in form .?

Answer (score 1):

use `img src` tag while show image

```
<td> 
  <img src="{{ Storage::url('uploads/'.$blog->image) }}" alt="image" width="50"> 
</td>
```

As you modify the name and store different name so change the code as below while saving the blog

```
$blog->image = $filename;
```

Comment: please check his code.Hes saving original file name into the table.

Answer (score 0):

````
public function stores(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg, png, jpg',
            'description' => 'required'
        ]);
         $image = $request->file('image');
        if(isset($image)) {

            //make unique name for the image
            $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
            $imageName = $currentDate. '-' .$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            //check for the presence of the directory
            if(!Storage::disk('public')->exists('uploads')) {
                Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('uploads');
            }
                //resize the image for uploads
                $uploads = Image::make($image)->resize(200, 200)->stream();
                Storage::disk('public')->put('uploads/' .$imageName, $uploads);

            } else {
            $blog->image = 'default.png'; 
        }
            $blog = new Blogform();   
            $blog->first_name = $request->firstname;
            $blog->last_name = $request->lastname;
            $blog->email = $request->email;
            $blog->image = $imageName;
            $blog->description = $request->description;
            $blog->save();
            return redirect('/blog')->with('successMsg', 'Blog form Submitted Successfully');

    }
```
The above codes works fine as it adds data perfectly to the database.
````

Comment: `
<img src="{{ Storage::disk('public')->url('/uploads/'.$blog->image) }}" >
`
to view the image for the above code